# Probability question choosing balls out of 7 balls

Tags: probability

Can someone help me with this question please

there are 7 balls labelled A, B, C, D, E, F, G
4 of these balls were selected randomly.

a). List a sample space displaying all the different possible selections of balls. **(i have no idea how to do this, isn't the sample space gonna be huge? how to set out the table for the sample space?)**

b). Find the probability that ball b and c were chosen.

c). Find the probability that ball a, b, c were chosen.

Please help me!!Thank you

Comment: The sample space is going to contain $\;\binom 74=35\;$ elements, so yes: it is pretty big to write it down in detail.

Comment: It will make a difference as to whether the selections are with or without replacement, and whether the order of draws matters.  @Joanpemo 's comment assumes without replacement and order not mattering

Answer (score 1):

The sample space contains all the subsets with four elements of the set $\;\{\,A,B,C,D,E,F,G\,\}\;$ , for example $\;\{A,B,C,D\}\;,\;\;\{A,B,D,F\}\;$ , etc., and their number is $\;\binom74=35\;$

If you already assume $\;B,C\;$ are in the subset of four elements chosen, then there remain $\;7-2=5\;$ elements from where to choose the other two elements, so the probability is

$$\frac{\binom52}{\binom74}$$

For (c) you already fixed three elements $\;A,B,C\;$ , so there are left $\;7-3=4\;$ elements from where to chose the fourth element...try to work out, similarly as above, the probability here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain to me why to use (5 2)/(7 4) to work out the probability of choosing B and C? I didn't really get that part. Thank you

Comment: @catherinelll . In finite cases (also in general but it is messier for me to explain), the probability of something is the number of events in the sample space that fulfill that something's condition divided by the total number of events in the space. That is exactly what happens here.